# Achartengine - How to use the same scale for two series?

Tags: graph, plot, scale, achartengine

I am trying to do a a graph with 3 series, based on MultipleTemperatureChart.
- The 3 series have the same x values.
- The 3 Y-axis have different values, but I am using only 2 Y-axis, and painting one with black color, to it does not show up.

I would like use the same scale for TWO, if I use "addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "Temperatura" }, x, y, Z);" * Z= scale , with the right scale, this is "3th" serie, so I use 3 as scale. everything is fine, but the scale is different.
BUT If I use 0 as a scale, so that my 3th serie has the same scale as 1st one has, O got some problem:
The graph show up OK, just like I want, but when I try to move the graph with the mouse in the AVD it stop !!!

Some one could help me ? 
Thanks.

Cláudio

```
public Intent getIntent(Context context) {
    String[] titles = new String[] { "Corrente" };
    List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    List<double[]> y = new ArrayList<double[]>();


    x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 });
    y.add(new double[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24 });

    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN };
    PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.POINT, PointStyle.POINT, PointStyle.POINT };

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(3);
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setPointSize(5f);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 20 });
    int length = colors.length;  //length é o total de series
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
       r.setColor(colors[i]);
       r.setPointStyle(styles[i]);
       renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      XYSeriesRenderer r = (XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
      r.setLineWidth(2f);
    }
    //titulo do gráfico
    renderer.setChartTitle("Curva 1");
    renderer.setXTitle("Tempo/hrs");
    renderer.setYTitle("Amperes/Graus °C" );
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.LTGRAY); 
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, colors[0]);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(1, colors[1]);
   // renderer.setYLabelsColor(2, Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setYTitle("volts", 1);
    renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 1);
    //quantia de valores "ticks"
    //renderer.setXLabels(24);                  
    //renderer.setYLabels(10);      
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(12);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(32);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0, 200, 0, 200 });
    renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { 0, 200, 0, 200 });
    renderer.setZoomRate(1.05f);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildDataset(titles, x, y);

    //---- gráfico de tensão
    y.clear();
    y.add(new double[] { 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "Tensão" }, x, y, 1);
    // ----- gráfico de temperatura
    y.clear();
    y.add(new double[] { 0, 11, 10, 10, 11, 10, 10, 10, 9, 10, 10, 10 });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "Temperatura" }, x, y, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = (XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
        // ---- seleciona qual gráfico preencher
        if (i == length - 1) {
          FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.NONE); //NONE mostra valores sobre o gráfico
          fill.setColor(Color.GREEN);
          seriesRenderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
        }
        seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2.5f);
        seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        seriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(10f);
      }

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getCubicLineChartIntent(context, dataset, renderer, 0.3f,
        "Average temperature");
    return intent;

}

public Intent execute(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Here the Log Error:

11-01 18:31:20.154: D/dalvikvm(9567): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 731 objects / 52992 bytes in 92ms
11-01 18:31:25.794: D/dalvikvm(9567): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6115 objects / 363864 bytes in 59ms
11-01 18:31:26.154: D/dalvikvm(9567): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8229 objects / 498936 bytes in 57ms
11-01 18:31:26.264: D/dalvikvm(9567): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
11-01 18:31:26.264: D/dalvikvm(9567): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
11-01 18:31:26.384: D/dalvikvm(9567): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
11-01 18:31:26.404: D/dalvikvm(9567): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
11-01 18:31:26.416: D/dalvikvm(9567): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
11-01 18:31:26.416: D/dalvikvm(9567): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
11-01 18:31:26.416: D/dalvikvm(9567): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
11-01 18:31:26.424: D/dalvikvm(9567): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
11-01 18:31:26.436: D/dalvikvm(9567): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
11-01 18:31:26.436: D/dalvikvm(9567): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
11-01 18:31:26.614: D/dalvikvm(9567): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6683 objects / 465000 bytes in 60ms

HERE the problem comes up.

11-01 18:31:30.658: D/AndroidRuntime(9567): Shutting down VM
11-01 18:31:30.658: W/dalvikvm(9567): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.toRealPoint(XYChart.java:877)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at org.achartengine.tools.Pan.apply(Pan.java:74)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at org.achartengine.TouchHandler.handleTouch(TouchHandler.java:119)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onTouchEvent(GraphicalView.java:300)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-01 18:31:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(9567):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Post the entire code, such as anyone can see your class extends AbstractDemoChart.

Comment: Thanks @Dan
I am using the same Original AbstractDemoChart, only changeed the name.
Just like this [https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/AbstractDemoChart.java]

Comment: Please share some logs.

Comment: @Dan if I Zoon in the graph, it does not stop. But if I move the graph to "min" points it stop.

Comment: @Dan Did you see the log above, is that you asked ?

Comment: This is probably a bug.

Comment: @Dan thanks for answering, I hope it can be fixed in the next releases. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this bug has been checked into SVN. You can download a version including this [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/).

Comment: Thanks, but the problem still happens.

I used the demo chart file.   - In the CombinedTemperatureChart I add one more series.   - I use the same scale for 2 or 3
    - I used the new lib

    If you zoom out at minus botton until you see -5 at x-scale, and try to move the graph, you will see the problem.

Comment: Mr.Dan Same problem exists with the updated jar If we zoom the graph and trying to pan when croosing the minimum limit ,it causes null pointer exception,,,need a solution thank you